# How to drop response of Async API calls in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created to APIs in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0, say API1 and API2. API2 is called asynchronously from API1. These two APIs hanlde 1.2 million requests everyday and each requests contains xml file size of 100KB to 500KB. We are forced to do frequnt server restarts due to high CPU utilization. Memory consumption is normal. One of the reason I suspect is Async flow is not able to clear the big XML from the contenxt and they are stacked up for couple of hours and CPU utilization is going up...May be I am not looking at the right place to solve the problem but I want to remove all these issues...quick help is appreciated here

Comment: Have you tried with drop mediator ?

Comment: I've not yet tried with drop mediator. Drop will drop the message but still it tried to send the response back to client

Comment: Not sure if I got you're point. Maybe the respond mediator helps. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Respond+Mediator

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the exact requirement at what exact point you want to drop the response. However I think you can analyze a thread dump and identify the threads what causes the unusual cpu utilization. For that you can execute top -H and get the thread list and get a thread dump and analyze stack trace of the threads causes the matter.

ps -ef | grep wso2esb 
           -- This will get the PID

jstack $PID > thread_dump.txt